# Making a deep copy using a constructor in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, deep-copy

I am using these instructions for the method:
    A constructor, public ProgrammingTeam( ProgrammingTeam p ), that takes a 
ProgrammingTeam p as a parameter and constructs a deep copy of p. Don’t just write meets = 
p.meets;. To make a deep copy, you must call ArrayList’s copy constructor: meets = new 
ArrayList();.

```
  public ProgrammingTeam( ProgrammingTeam p ) {
    teamName = p.teamName;
    teamMembers = new String [ p.teamMembers.length ];
    for (int i = p.teamMembers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    }
    meets = new ArrayList < Competition >();
}
```

I cannot figure out exactly how I am supposed to compose and then finish the deep copy. I know it is going to need a for loop to actually copy every object but I am at a loss, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the String array...

Strings are immutable, so it is sufficient to simply copy the array, for example using the [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) utility method:

```
teamMembers = Arrays.copyOf( p.teamMembers, p.teamMembers.length );
```

---

As for the List, it depends...

If `Competition` is [*immutable*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), use ArrayList's copy constructor:

```
meets = new ArrayList<Competition>(p.meets);
```

If `Competition` is mutable, you need to invoke its copy constructor (defining it if required).

```
meets = new ArrayList<Competition>();
for (Competition c : p.meets) {
    meets.add(new Competition(c));
}
```

Comment: I tried the teamMembers suggestion, but it isn't allowing it. Possibly because the actual variable is private String[] teamMembers;?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't allowing it"? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a deep copy of all of the ProgrammingTeam parameter p's attributes.

You could do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < p.teamMembers.length -1; i++){
        TeamMember teamMember = new TeamMember();
        // set attributes
        teamMember.setAttribute1(p.teamMembers[i].getAttribute1());
        ...
        teamMember.setAttributeN(p.teamMembers[i].getAttributeN());
         this.teamMembers[i] = teamMember;
 }
```

Of course, you could simply create a copy constructor for whatever objects are held in the lists that need to be deep copied.  The copy constructor would essentially need to accomplish the same sort of thing I described within that for loop.

Answer (score 0):

To make a deep copy of `String[] teamMembers` use `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(teamMembers, teamMembers.length)`

As for a deep copy of `List<Competition> meets` you can do it with `new ArrayList<Competition>(meets)` but it will only be good if Competition is immutable